# How do I properly execute "flex-row" in this instance?

Tags: css, reactjs, styling

I'm attempting to have a portion of my React code appear in an in-line block using "flex-row" as a class name, but it's not working. I've looked at other questions and haven't been able to find the answer needed (I'm attempting it without using the "View" wrapper). My code is as follows (but my result is does not show the list in an in-line block; see attached image below):

```
<header data-testid="header" className="flex-row px-1">
 <nav>
  <ul className="flex-row">
     <li className="mx-2">
       <a href="#language" onClick={() => handleClick()}>
          Language
       </a>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href="#about" onClick={() => handleClick()}>
          About Us
       </a>
     </li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</header>
```

[image: screenshot of flex-row NOT showing]

I feel like it's a simple fix, but any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: can we see the css flex-flow has, and maybe a screenshot of what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using TailwindCSS. If so add a `flex` class before "flex-row" in  element. Hope this will sort your issue/.

```
<header data-testid="header" className="flex-row px-1">
 <nav>
  <ul className="flex flex-row">
     <li className="mx-2">
       <a href="#language" onClick={() => handleClick()}>
          Language
       </a>
     </li>
     <li>
       <a href="#about" onClick={() => handleClick()}>
          About Us
       </a>
     </li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

It truly was a simple fix...lol. I had code for the navigation options "Language" and "About Us" to be in an in-line block (hence the "flex-row" denomination), yet I have `<li>` tags around the two navigation options. Once I took off the tag, it worked. Thanks, everyone! [corrected image displayed here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfzAB.png)